# Ссылки и указатели

Tags: g++, указатели, ссылки, c++

Я думаю, все знают про ссылки и указатели. 
В общем, когда я попытался вывести на экран адрес переменной (`cout << &a << endl;`), я получил шестнадцатеричное число. Что оно означает и имеет ли смысл для программиста?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Оно означает адрес в памяти, где хранится переменная a. Оно обычно полезно при отладке.

Answer (score 5):

Через ссылку программист может изменить значение переменной, а можно просто передать эту ссылку какой либо функции, вместо копирования всего объекта. Смысл разумеется имеется, но не в самом шестнадцатеричном числе, а в восприятии этого числа.

Answer (score 1):

Будет иметь смысл при передаче аргументов посредством указателей, вместо целых больших данных. При инициализации указателя в его память записывается посредством & адрес объекта. И эта переменная при передаче в функцию как показывает ей где хранятся эти данные в памяти программы.